# LINQ в Go. Почему нет?

Tags: golang, linq, дизайн-языка

У меня есть вопрос про [linq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). Почему в Go до сих пор нет в стандарте этой чудесной штуки. Всё, что я слышал до сих пор по эту технологию от гоферов, так это то, что это не по-гоферному. К сожалению, этот аргумент меркнет, когда тебе нужно сделать пару группировок, а потом ещё пару проекций. В итоге, 3-4 строки трансформируются 3-4 экрана. По-моему выбор очевиден. Да, есть проблемы. Например, для реализации LINQ, скорее всего потребуется `reflect`, что приведёт к просаживанию производительности. Но при этом, не стоит забывать, что с таким же успехом, можно сказать, что и сам `reflect` приводит к тому, что производительность просаживается. Так давайте от него откажемся. Конечно, этого никто не сделает. Вопрос в том, где корректно использовать ту или иную технологию.

Кстати говоря, аналог `reflect` есть. Это статическая генерация кода. Например, так реализованы [некоторые](https://github.com/json-iterator/go) [не стандартные](https://github.com/mailru/easyjson) пакеты в Go для работы с JSON.

Для ознакомления с технологией LINQ в го, привожу [ссылку](https://medium.com/wesovilabs/koazee-vs-go-funk-vs-go-linq-caf8ef18584e).

---

Я завёл [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32926) в основной репе golang. Требуется достаточно весомое обоснование для открытие такого issue.

---

Продолжая моё исследования linq для golang, я нашёл [следующее](https://github.com/wesovilabs/koazee-comparison/pull/1). Здесь человек производит сравнение [koazee](https://github.com/wesovilabs/koazee) и обычных циклов. Легко заметить, что он приходит к выводу, что koazee не сильно уступает нативному golang. Обсуждение [здесь](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/a2yjtj/koazee_vs_golinq_vs_gofunk/). К слову, скажу, koazee -- лучшая реализация linq для golang. Лучшая == самая быстрая и функциональная на момент **09.07.2019**.

---

Одна из неудобных вещей в golang и linq -- это способ обращения к лямбдам. Так как в golang нет шаблонов, придётся писать конструкции, которые похожи на эти:

```
From(cars).Where(func(c interface{}) bool {
    return c.(Car).year >= 2015
}).Select(func(c interface{}) interface{} {
    return c.(Car).owner
})
```

Всем очевидно, что данная конструкция громоздкая и неудобно читается. Более того, здесь происходит приведение интерфейса к типу, что также не является хорошим тоном. В оправдание скажем, что отказ от такого рода конструкций, приводит к ещё более неудобным вещам: нескольким функциям, которые могут оказаться ещё менее читаемые, особенно, если разработчик не аккуратен. Спещу заметить, с большой вероятностью, эти функции будут возвращать ошибки в качестве возвращаемых значений, что только увеличит объём кода.

В [go-linq](https://github.com/ahmetb/go-linq) создателям удалось добиться эмуляции шаблонов:

```
From(cars).Where(func(c Car) bool {
    return c.year >= 2015
}).Select(func(c Car) string {
    return c.owner
})
```

При этом, [скорее всего](https://medium.com/wesovilabs/koazee-vs-go-funk-vs-go-linq-caf8ef18584e) (если ничего не изменилось), go-linq много медленнее, koazee.

Взято [отсюда](http://kalan.rocks/2017/02/24/go-linq-v3-0-emulating-generics-in-go/). **09.07.2019**

---

[Ещё](https://github.com/icholy/higher)  одна библиотека, которая ничего не упоминает про linq, но реализует похожий функционал. Не поддерживается, к сожалению.  **09.07.2019**

Comment: Негодование понятно. Но какой ответ вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: так вроде сделали? [package linq](https://godoc.org/github.com/ahmetb/go-linq)

Comment: Имхо, вы не в ту сторону воюете. LINQ - это хорошо, это удобно. Однако, во многих (функциональных, обычно) языках есть не менее удобный синтаксис для работы с коллекциями. Требуйте лучше введения метапрограммирования (макросов) в Go. Тогда любой синтаксис будет реализовываться элементарно (пойду всплакну по языку Nemerle...)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я боюсь, что вряд ли это возможно. LINQ будет сложно продавить. А вот метапрограммирование, про которое я и сам толком ничего не знаю -- вообще невозможно. Хотя бы потому что, я не знаю хороших воплощений этой концепции в golang. Насколько я понимаю, отчасти метапрограммирование реализовано в пакете `reflect`

Comment: Кстати, в Мелкософте и не только осознали, что linq to objects имеет врождённые проблемы с производительностью и давно уже стали появляться [библиотеки](https://github.com/antiufo/roslyn-linq-rewrite), прозрачно переписывающие декларативный код linq в императивные циклы, более эффективные. Зачем я это пишу? Ну, радуюсь этому факту :).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, к сожалению, я не готов изучать эту историю и предлагать её другим -- тем паче. Это слишком сложно для меня. Я точно не справлюсь. Что касается LINQ -- у меня есть потребности и я их решаю.

Answer (score 5):

На этот вопрос вам точно ответят только в Go Team, но ответ скорее всего будет около следующего.

Во-первых, для LINQ à la C# нужны обобщённые коллекции типа `IEnumerable<T>`, которые если и появятся, то только в Go 2.0. На интерфейсах это всё пойдёт через отражение, что медленно, и местами небезопасно.

Во-вторых, само название «Language Integrated Query» говорит, что нужна поддержка со стороны языка. Это означает новые ключевые слова, причём не одно. Учитывая, что Go Team крайне неохотно добавляет ключевые слова, их добавление крайне маловероятно. Не говоря уже о том, что это синтаксический сахар.

В-третьих, даже если опустить синтаксис, для LINQ понадобятся анонимные функции с выведением типов, что является ещё одним расширением языка, и что вряд ли появится даже в Go 2.0.

Comment: LINQ на `IEnumerable<T>` и анонимных функциях - это небольшое подмножество LINQ, LINQ to Objects, "синтаксический сахар". Основная часть LINQ в C#, из-за которой фича оказалась такой успешной - это LINQ на `IQueryable<T>` (query object), с компиляцией лямбд не в функции, а в деревья выражений. Она позволяет отображать код на C# в соответствующие SQL запросы - и такое просто через обобщенные коллекции провернуть не получится

Comment: @PashaPash да, не получится. Но даже `IEnumerable<T>` сильно бы упростил жизнь. Я знаю об этой проблеме не по наслышке. Это особенно сильно стало заметно во время трансляции C# проекта -> golang ипостасию.

Comment: Новые ключевые слова вовсе не обязательны. В LINQ есть два вида [синтаксиса](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq): query syntax (нужны новые ключевые слова) и method syntax (сделано на методах расширения). Можно ограничиться вторым способом.

Comment: @PashaPash, ответы - в ответы.